# Why does my company keep putting me under the same manager?

Tags: manager

I'm a software developer in a large company.

About six months ago, there was some reorganisation on my team, and I got put under a new manager "Bob".  The weird thing is that I was the *only* person that reported to Bob.  As far as I know, he didn't have any other responsibilities other than people managing me.  As a result, he would crazy micro-manage me.  Some days, he would stand behind me for hours when I would code and shout out random suggestions.  (I just don't think he had anything to do most of the day.)

Finally, I had enough and looked for a new job.  So a month ago, I got another job in the same company, but much different team and organisation, doing completely different work.  (I was a .NET developer building backend APIs, and now I'm a front-end developer focused on our main external platform).  It was a breath of fresh air and went back to a normal team structure.

Well, last week, we had a [town hall meeting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Town_hall_meeting#Other_uses_of_the_term) and they announced a reorganisation.  It was not too surprising, since they're constantly changing things around in my company.  However, the surprising part is that my old manager, Bob, is getting moved into our organisation, and I'll be reporting to him.  The even stranger part is that the seven other developers on my team will be reporting to one manager, and I'll be the only person reporting to Bob.  So somehow, I'm back in the exact same situation!

Is my company trying to tell me something with this move?  This all seems super bizarre, but I have only been in the industry for six years, so I don't know how normal this is.  Should I speak up or voice my concerns?

Comment: I doubt anyone (but your company) can tell you, but having a different manager to your team mates seems odd enough to ask about. How is that a team, if different people set your priorities?

Comment: Have you raised this oddity that you have a different manager than everyone else to anyone?  It is possible that there was a glitch and they put your old manager in rather than the new manager you should be under.

Comment: @Anketam: That starts to sound like the plot of John Steakley's _Armor_ (lone survivor of space trooper brigade gets sent into battles indefinitely, b/c no one bothered to clear the record in the database)

Comment: How very odd. I'd love to hear an update if you ever find out.

Comment: Is it possible that they feel that Bob needs some “reverse management” and you are seen as the best person for the job? I assume no one has had a direct conversation about this with you, but have you had any cryptic conversations that, with hindsight, might explain it?

Comment: Don't frame it as voicing your concern. Frame it as voicing your curiosity.

Comment: Management may assume that you two work well together, so why break up the dynamic-duo?

Comment: Is your last name [NULL](http://www.wired.com/story/null-license-plate-landed-one-hacker-ticket-hell)?

Comment: [A glitch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zqjQDP9KX6E&t=29s) (fixed by the Bobs).

Answer (score 66):

There are 3 possibilities:

- You
- Bob
- Bureaucracy

If the problem was *you* then I doubt that you would have been able to get another position elsewhere in the company. You might get stuck in one position for a long time (reluctance to fire you unless there was a clear and serious problem) buy you wouldn't get moved around into different departments *of your choosing*.

The problem could be *Bob*. Perhaps Bob is only suitable for a management role due to limited technical skills. Combine that with some reason that Bob can't be fired (owner's nephew or whatever). So Bob gets shuffled around and made a manager in the smallest way possible - managing one person. You have a reputation as a good employee, not needing much *useful* management oversight, so you get Bob. Move to a new department and Bob now needs someone to manage. You're still in the company, so you get Bob and Bob gets you. If this is the case then you just have to figure out how to keep Bob from being too intrusive ("Bob, if you don't bother me, I won't bother you, we'll meet for 5 minutes each morning and 1 hour once a week and the rest of the time I'll code and you have free time") and you both have it easy.

And the problem could be *bureaucracy*. You moved, Bob was now free, HR system eventually paired you with Bob again using some algorithm but not any real serious thought. If that's the case, discussing it with another manager is the way to go.

Comment: This is actually an answerable question, and the above answer is a good example of what an answer could be for such a question.

Comment: Agree that they may be looking for _someone_ for Bob to manage.

Comment: In the "You" case, it is possible that OP is recognised as a good worker, but who needs to be micro-managed to be most efficient. So they identified it the first time, assigned Bob to micromanage OP, and by whatever metric it was deemed to work (for the company). OP then requests a move, someone in HR who is not aware of the issue says OK, and a few months later they notice that OP's performance is not as good as expected, and they apply the same method, get Bob in. Of course that would require that the productivity of OP is so much better with Bob that the cost of Bob is compensated.

Comment: In the "Bob" case, maybe Bob has a crush on OP and enough "power" (owner's nephew or whatever, as you write) to ask to be paired with OP and get it.

Comment: @jcaron unlikely

Comment: A pretty good answer. But for case 2, I'd focus on truly solving the problem (not having Bob as manager, being in scope with rest of team... heck, OP achieved it briefly before), rather than committing to a corrupt ghetto.

Answer (score 36):

We can't really answer the 'Why does the company do this' - but there is a question here that we can answer:

You can absolutely talk with HR/Management (not him) and express your concerns/desires.

Let them know that you've worked under them previously and you didn't enjoy the experience hence your lateral move in the organization. Make the business case as to why you should be reporting to the same manager as the other Devs.

It's most likely whoever re-org'd it looked and said 'Oh, he worked under Bob previously, we'll do that again!' without knowing the reasons why you did the lateral move.

It's okay to question decisions when an entity has re-organized and to make the case why certain decisions may be sub-optimal.

Answer (score 14):

One answer I haven’t seen is that Bob might like you.

I once had a manager who I actually hated and felt like he was treating me very harshly and worse than most other employees. It was a part-time job during college and basically you had to reapply every year and were able to switch managers/positions every year. I was the only one who were put under him every year. This went on for like five years and then became his assistant manager for my last year.

Before I quit for good he told me that he always selected me and requested that I was put under him. He said that he thought I was the only one who was capable enough for the job. Which of course surprised me because he was always so harsh, but apparently he just expected more of me than from other employees so he wouldn’t let small mistakes slide.

So maybe Bob is in a similar situation and just requests to manage you all the time.
Or Bob might not be very technical and thinks he can learn most of you.

In the end, the only thing you can do to find out is ask Bob himself if he knows why he always manages you or ask other managers or HR.

Comment: +1: But I'd ask other managers, not Bob. That feels risky.

Answer (score 4):

> Is my company trying to tell me something with this move?

You need to find out.

> This all seems super bizarre, but I have only been in the industry for 6 years, so I don't know how normal this is.

Yep, it is bizarre.
It isn't super-bizarre in my opinion, but neither is it normal.

> Should I speak up or voice my concerns?

Yes, you should speak up.
Life is too short to be miserable - if you can avoid it (as you did previously when you moved).

Specifically, you should speak to the manager that the 7 other devs report to.
Ask *that manager* informally, and in private, why you are reporting to Bob instead of him/her.
That answer will tell you if you need to go to another company to get away from Bob.

With the .NET skills you mentioned, you should have no problem changing between companies if that is necessary.

I wouldn't recommend you ask HR about anything - unless you were being harassed, bullied, etc.  You won't generally get a straight answer from HR on something like this, and the questions they start asking (if they do anything) can create misunderstandings and be a problem for you in the future.

Answer (score 2):

> Is my company trying to tell me something with this move?

No idea. It may be that the company is convinced that the combination of the two of you is a key to success. Or it may be that they believe that you need to be micromanaged. or it could be that nobody else will work for that manager. or something else.

> This all seems super bizarre, but I have only been in the industry for
> 6 years, so I don't know how normal this is.

I have seen a lot of interesting management decisions. I have seen non-technical people in roles made for people with technical skills. I have seen mangers be overwhelmed with a staff of two. I have seen situations were every manager managed 20 people. I have see micro-managers, and I don't care managers.

> Should I speak up or voice my concerns?

Find a manager that you trust and talk to them. See if you can convince them to explain the why of the decision.

Answer (score -4):

Just quit. As a software developer you'll find a new job in no time, and because rotation costs them, they'll have to consider giving you a counter-offer... and then you get to choose your manager.

Comment: *and then you get to choose your manager* - How does that work? Make it a condition of employment and I doubt they'll agree - and besides, even if you "choose" your manager, when (s)he moves to a different department or quits for any reason the company gets to bring back Bob anyway.

Comment: [Is 'Quit your job' an acceptable answer?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1697/168)

Comment: There is a lot of survivorship bias in accounts of software developers finding a new job just like that.

Comment: No guys, it's not a bias. Because software developers routinely don't like to spend money (we're more geeks than we're show-offs, at least those of us who value financial independence), we're actually more often than not in a position to NOT work for several months. We also tend to not have too many children, as sitting all day at computer is not a very sexy job. We seriously think, that more of normal people could gain a lot of power by being less afraid of their bosses. Just saying.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact how would that work? You simply don't care who your manager is, if you are no longer managed by that company. They could, in theory, ask for honest reason, beg your forgiveness and re-hire you, if they cared about business, not about their petty power over your life.